# How to get action class by action name in struts2?

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to find out which action class will be used to perform action with a given name?

Thank you

Comment: [Here may be the possible solution...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131602/java-struts2-how-to-get-action-name-from-current-url)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you need this information at runtime. This will give you the action class name for the specified package and action name.

```
Dispatcher.getInstance()
    .getConfigurationManager()
    .getConfiguration()
    .getPackageConfig("packageName")
    .getActionConfigs()
    .get("actionName")
    .getClassName()
```

You can get the actual class too, if needed, along with lots of other information from the `Configuration` class.

Note: If you do not absolutely know the package and action name exists, then don't chain that call or you will probably get a NullPointerException.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work with convention plugin when no mappings defined explicitly in struts.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a sanity check during testing use the config-browser-plugin it will provide this information already on nicely formated pages: https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/config-browser-plugin.html