# Java/Struts2: How to get action name from current url

Tags: java, struts2

I am having a active page with  its  url like `http://localhost:8085/projectName/namespace1/namespace2/namespace3/sell.action?id=22`

Now i want get the  action name(4th name after the sign `/`) i.e setuppageforwared.

How to achieve this ? Please help me to know because i read many books of struts2 i could not find anything which solve this problem.

Before i was using PHP framework `codeigniter` which easily solve this type of problem using  [uri segment features(click here)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)   . I am aspecting the same here in Struts2.

---

***Given Url String***: `http://localhost:8085/projectName/namespace1/namespace2/namespace3/sell.action?id=22`

***Expected Output***: `sell`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you look for `ActionContext#getName()` ?

**Edit** :
Since you were not clear about it, I suppose you want to get the name of the action being executed from inside the action. So, in your action `execute` method, you'll have something like this :

> String actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getName();

Comment: How to use this , can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Okay i got it . Its working fine.Now i will set property for `actionName` variable to the action, and then retrieve that property from the value stack via OGNL into my jsp page....THanks again

Comment: @Sundara http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html, but this is completely unrelated, OT for SO, and took about thirty seconds on Google.

Comment: please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150980/downloading-spring-framework-latest-release