# unable to Download Spring Framework jar files

Tags: spring, download

From last half and hour , i was trying to download spring framework library but still could not. I am following this [this tutorial(click here)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5gubdHLJIc) , so as they are saying i could not found any jars 
for which author is representing. 
Looks like Spring site has been updated. I am very confused. Please help me how to download the jars as shown in the video [from the spring website?](http://spring.io/projects)

Though, i downloaded by following [Spring Home](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) >> [this zip](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) ,but after unzipping it ,it does not contain any jars.
***I am confused right now  because spring site has been newly updated.***

**I would like to get the files as shown in this image**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Spring Site can be found at `https://spring.io/`

But the best way to download the compiled jar, is to download them from the maven repository.

Grab the maven groupId, artefactId, and version from the project page (The Spring core libs can be found on subpage `Projects` / `Spring Framework` (in the middle of the first row))

Currently it is

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The go to the maven repository

- Maven Central http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav , or
- Spring Source Maven Repository http://repo.spring.io/webapp/gavcsearch.html

enter groupId and artefactId, and download the `jar` artifact.

---

( http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework|spring-context|3.2.5.RELEASE|jar )

Comment: see my rewritten answer

Comment: As a beginner, i prefer to download spring in this format http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/spring_directories.jpg

Comment: You can download the jars form `http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=spring+core`

Comment: @Sundara I have watched the video a bit, and this is clearly NOT the way you should go today anymore.

Comment: @Ralph okay, so please can you find other easy video which you recommend me to watch and learn. And how to set library for Spring. I am first time learning SPRING. I know Struts2 & Hibernate

Comment: @Sundara: I strongly recommend that you use maven for the spring libary management (in maven terms: dependencies). Spring itselfe has a tutorial how to start with spring and maven: http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

Comment: And then have a look at the tutorials located at spring.io: at the **BOTTOM** of this page http://spring.io/guides

Comment: thanks, & as you said above to download spring jar. I followed it as you said but it downloaded only one jar i.e `spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar` . Is this enough to implement basic of spring using this only one jar?

Comment: In Most Cases Not. In the Maven Repository you will find an other file, called the ´pom.xml´ next to the jar you downloaded. -- This contains a list (dependencies) of other libraries that is required. -- If you uses Maven instead, maven will download the pom and then download the other references, and then referenced for the references,...