# Unable to download Spring3 from the spring website

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring framework and for the first program. I'm trying to download Spring jars and many websites gave "http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/" link and there is no download provision there.

Trying to download Spring jars for past one hour. 
Can someone provide me a link where I can download Spring jars.

- spring-source.jar
- common-loggings.jar

Comment: You can download the bundle from the [repository](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/).

Comment: You can search for binaries [here](http://mvnrepository.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. it did not allow me to ask question as it has been repeated so i have added some extra words. apologies for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to Download Spring Framework jar files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150980/unable-to-download-spring-framework-jar-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150980/unable-to-download-spring-framework-jar-files

Answer (score 0):

best option its add spring to maven dependency and then You dont need woory about, from where take spring jars

Comment: Although this is an option (and the one I indeed use), it might not always be the "best". For example, a defense contractor with closed areas that cannot ping the Maven repositories for security reasons.